# Anchor link going above the anchor in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have anchor links in the menu that go to an anchor on the page, however in Firefox the anchor seems to go above the actual anchor - however in Chrome, it takes you exactly to where the anchor is - from a little testing i've done, it seems that the issue is related to the padding.

You can see the issue here; www.anjoykitchen.co.uk/

Click on Menu & Takeaway or About in the menu and it will (in Firefox) take you to the anchor with a gap at the top; yet on Chrome it takes you to the exact place you'd expect it to.

Comment: I get the same behaviour in both browsers... What I do see though it that the first time I click the link it's slightly above and then if I scroll back up and click it again I am in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same ID that your linking to on two different elements:

```
<section id="menu" class="menu-container">
    <header class="menu-title">
        <h2 id="menu">Anjoy Kitchen Menu and Takeaway</h2>
```

ID's should be unique on a page, only appearing on one element in the DOM.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to remove one. But the issue still remains none the less.

Comment: Bizarre, sorry about that, though that was the cause. I can't find out why it's doing that.